# How to turn iOS framework into module

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, frameworks

I have an iOS framework that I created but everything in it is set to 'Project' scope, i.e. I don't want to make anything public and have been happily including the project in other apps that share the same framework. I've now recently started using Swift for the new project. I linked with the existing framework and added a Custom View to one of my View Controllers in Interface Builder. The app seems to compile, link and run just fine, and the custom view shows up fine too. However when I create an IBOutlet into my swift file, all of a sudden it complains `Use of undeclared type` for my custom class and won't compile anymore. If I try to `import MyFramework` it complains that it can't find any such module.

So the question is, how do I convert a Project scoped framework into a Module and how do I make this class visible in Swift? IB seems to have no issues and clearly the app is linking and running just fine. It just won't let me access the class inside my swift code. Please help!

Comment: You can import framework in Bridging-Header.h class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In yourProject-Bridging-Header.h,

```
#import <YourFramework/YourFramework.h>
```